# Run MySQL command line from Java program

Tags: java, mysql, windows

I have to dump a mysql DB schema(structure + data) into a text file.
I'm using the command below, but no data is exported, I have no error when the function is called...

```
public void dumpFullDB() throws IOException {
  String[] cmd = new String[]{"mysqldump ",
      "test > C:\\Users\\Andrei\\Desktop\\Tema Alcatel\\IntApp\\schema.sql"
  };
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the output to the console of the command? Does your database actually let  you dump it with no credentials?

Comment: You're missing a few options, like for authentication and so on...

Comment: there is no authentication.. I have a the db on a local server

Comment: java.lang.ProcessImpl@6086d3a8  this is the output

Comment: @AndreiMaieras That's what you get if you just print the `Process` object. Instead read the exit value and check the error output stream. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html.

Comment: An example on how to read the exit value?